How to estimate thermal conductivity of a sample?
There is a rectangular sample whose emissivity is known, and I want to estimate its thermal conductivity. A heater with a known heat flux is applied to one end of the sample and a fixed temperature is applied to the other end. If two sections are selected along the direction of heat transfer (As shown in the figure) and the heat flux and temperature passing through both sections are known, can the thermal conductivity of the sample be obtained from these conditions? (We also need to take into account the heat radiation loss, we know the ambient temperature, and the environment is a vacuum so we don't consider convection)

I used COMSOL to do the simulation (the function is steady-state). I wanted to use the temperature gradient and net heat flow (the total heat flow into the material minus the radiation loss) to get the thermal conductivity, but the results were not accurate. I later found that using the heat flux in the middle of the material to calculate the thermal conductivity was very accurate (perhaps because I set the temperature probe to be symmetrical along the midpoint of the material?). May I ask why? Is there a formula or theory to support it?
